# How do I split() the result of a split()?

Tags: pyspark, databricks

My PySpark data field has a column with a value of the form `0000-00-00-00-00-00-000_000.xxxx` where `0` is a digit and `x` is a letter. The value represents an observation timestamp with some other values mixed in.

In my notebook, I have a cell that attempts to split the column containing the timestamp. For the most part, it works.I get most of the work done with the following:

```
`splitDF = ( df
.withColumn("fn_year", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(0))
.withColumn("fn_month", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(1))
.withColumn("fn_day", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(2))
.withColumn("fn_hour", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(3))
.withColumn("fn_min", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(4))
.withColumn("fn_sec", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(5))
.withColumn("fn_milli", split(df["fn"], "-").getItem(6))
)`
```

I need to extract two values from the string; the 000 preceding the underscore and the 000 following the underscore. I would normally (my usual language / environment is C# / .NET 7, web API stuff) just split the string multiple times using the two delimiters ('_' and '.') and grab the necessary components. I can't get that to work in this case. When I try to pass the split into another split I get `["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]` for the result (`.getItem(x)` omitted).

Here's an example of what I thought might work to split on the underscore and then the period:
`splitDF = df.withColumn("fn_qc", split(split(df["fn"], "_").getItem(1), ".").getItem(0))`

Comment: The nested split should work fine, could you tell me what should be desired value in `fn_qc`? Like you said you want 2 strings, but do you want to concatenate them or have them in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically we split string based on dash - it would return an array which is used across. In the last statement, we split again based on underscore. For the last value you could use a substring or split again based on period or just replace xxxx if it is a static value...
Hope this helps.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col, substring
date_list = [["2023-01-02-03-04-05-666_777.xxxx"], ["2023-12-11-10-09-08-444_333.xxxx"]]
cols = ["fn"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(date_list, cols)

splitDF = df.withColumn("split_on_dash", split(col("fn"), "-")) \
.withColumn("fn_year", col("split_on_dash")[0]) \
.withColumn("fn_month", col("split_on_dash")[1]) \
.withColumn("fn_day", col("split_on_dash")[2]) \
.withColumn("fn_hour", col("split_on_dash")[3]) \
.withColumn("fn_min", col("split_on_dash")[4]) \
.withColumn("fn_sec", col("split_on_dash")[5]) \
.withColumn("fn_milli", split(col("split_on_dash")[6], "_")[0]) \
.withColumn("fn_after_underscore", substring(split(col("split_on_dash")[6], "_")[1], 0, 3))
display(splitDF)
```

You can select only the required columns later or drop the unnecessary ones...
[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You example works but, unfortunately, I'm going to need to split for the last value. There are 1..n characters in that string. I changed your example to split the split but now the `fn_after_underscore` column is empty. Here's the change I made `.withColumn("fn_after_underscore", split(split(col("split_on_dash")[6], "_")[1], ".")[0])`

Comment: It turns out the period character needed to be escaped. Once I did that, splitting the split result worked as I initially thought it should. Here's the updated last line `.withColumn("fn_after_underscore", split(split(col("split_on_dash")[6], "\.")[0], "_")[1])`

Comment: Cool !!! Glad you had it solved...